# Saving an Outlook email attachment with Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, email-attachments, office-automation

I'm using some modified code I found online to query one of my Outlook folders that currently has 1 email in it with a .csv attachment: `TEST.CSV`

```
# use MAPI name space
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application; 
$mapi = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");

# go to Inbox folder (6)
$olDefaultFolderInbox = 6
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder($olDefaultFolderInbox) 

# go to the sub-folder 
$olFolderPath = "\\my.path\Inbox\tester"

$targetFolder = $inbox.Folders | Where-Object { $_.FolderPath -eq $olFolderPath }

# load emails
$emails = $targetFolder.Items

Write-Host $emails.Count
```

At this point, I can see that I have `1` email, as expected.

```
$emails[1].Attachments

Write-Host $emails[1].Attachments[1].FileName
```

At this point, several lines of information are returned, and the filename `TEST.CSV`
What i'd like to do is save `TEST.CSV` locally, at `C:\Users\myid\Documents`

When I try the following lines:

```
$fileName = $emails[1].Attachments[1].FileName

# set the path
$filePath = "C:\Users\myid\Documents"

# save the file
$_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filePath $fileName))
```

I get the following error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\myid\Documents\testcode.ps1:43 char:1
+ $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filePath $fileName))
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Although `Write-Host $fileName` returns: `TEST.CSV`, I seem to be missing something.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're not passing anything through a pipeline to `$_.saveasfile`, `$_` is a null value

Answer (score 1):

First of all, iterating over all subfolders and checking the folder path string is not a good idea in Outlook:

```
$targetFolder = $inbox.Folders | Where-Object { $_.FolderPath -eq $olFolderPath }
```

Instead, you may get a subfolder by using its name, see the [Folders.Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders.item) method which returns a `Folder` object from the collection. You may pass either the index number of the object, or a value used to match the default property of an object in the collection (name). For example:

```
Sub AddToFavorites() 
 
 'Adds a Public Folder to the List of favorites 
 
 Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set objFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders.Item("GroupDiscussion").Folders.Item("Standards").Folders.Item("Internal") 
 
 objFolder.AddToPFFavorites 
 
End Sub
```

To save the attached file you need to use the [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method of the `Attachment` class:

```
$attachment = $emails[1].Attachments[1]
$fileName = $attachment.FileName

# set the path
$filePath = "C:\Users\myid\Documents"

# save the file
$attachment.saveasfile((Join-Path $filePath $fileName))
```

Comment: this didn't quite get me where I needed to be; but, I appreciate your help!